# maximum xor is with closest number

Tags: algorithm, max, xor

If I have a list `L` of positive integers and I am given another number `K`, I need to find the number in the list with which XOR of `K` is maximum.

I have thought of an algorithm for this. I want to verify its correctness with counter arguments. My algorithm is:

- **Find `P`=K's complement (1's complement). Now find the number which is closest to P in the list L. Let this number be N. The XOR of K and N will be maximum.**
- Closest number to a number `I` in a given set of numbers is a number whose difference with I is minimum.

Lets say, it is not correct for the numbers greater than `P` in the list `L`. But isn't it correct for the numbers `<=P` ?

Please tell me whether I am correct or not by providing counter arguments/suggestions/ideas.

Comment: Closest <-- How do you define this?

Comment: What, closest numerically? Then it will of course be false.

Comment: @user1708762: No, it won't work. I remember doing a programming problem and this approach gives wrong answer for some cases. I don't want to bother constructing counter example now, though.

Comment: @user1708762: In binary, K = 0000 1011 --> P = 1111 0100 , L = {0000, 1000, 0000 0100, 0000 0011}. You will end up choosing 3 (0000 0011), since its difference with P (a negative number) is smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need something called a [`Trie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

consider every bit of `K`, from higher to lower, of course we can be greedy when determine whether this bit of answer can be `1`, i mean, first you try your best to get `1024`(or even higher), and then `512`, and then `256` and then......finally to the last bit `1`.

So first you need to check whether some number in the list `L` has the opposite value to `K` in the highest bit, then among all the chosen numbers, then you need to find the numbers which has the opposite value to `K` in the second highest bit.

now the solution is obvious, build a `Trie` with `L`, determine the answer's bits from higher to lower, which corresponds to travel on that tree.

Answer (score 0):

No, not right.

Let `K = 0011`, so that `P = 1100`. Let `L = {0011, 1100}`. Your algorithm would choose `N = 1100`, which is obviously incorrect since `N^K = 0`, while `0011^N = 3`.

Answer (score -1):

Coding and running the obvious brute-force algorithm would have taken far less time than you've already spent on this.

Comment: Usually, the point of optimization is to make it always run fast, not to make it run fast once.

Comment: I didn't see any mention of optimization.  Anyway, XOR is blindingly fast on almost any architecture - trying to cheese-pare a few CPU cycles is pointless.

Comment: Sure, but you could make an algorithm that pre-processed `L` in a such a way that all such queries against that `L` were really fast (e.g. `log(N)` fast). Such an algorithm might be critical in some kinds of problems (e.g. multiple maximum-subset searches against a large, fixed collection of bitsets). In that case, even if XOR is fast, 10000 `O(log(N))` queries will beat the pants off 10000 `O(N)` queries for big enough `N`.

Comment: @WaywiserTundish: Your answer actually is a good solution if the numbers are arbitrary. One case where this is a bad solution is when the list is defined as a continuous a range of numbers, defined with upper and lower bound.

Comment: We were told nothing about any special properties of either L or K.  In the absence of further information, one must assume arbitrary inputs.  If you can find an algorithm for random integer L where the run time isn't dominated by by the sort or peak find function, I'll buy the next round.